# How to calculate aggregates for sub-trees in Gremlin?

Tags: tree, aggregate, gremlin

I have a tree with many levels, where leaf nodes might have property "count".
I want to calculate total count for each sub-tree, and cache those values in the root node of each sub-tree.
Is that possible in Gremlin?

Comment: which version of Gremlin 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: Gremlin 2.x would be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it with a `sideEffect` - that's pretty straightforward.  We setup a simple tree with:

```
gremlin> g = new TinkerGraph()                                                                 
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> v1 = g.addVertex()                                                                    
==>v[0]
gremlin> v2 = g.addVertex()                                                                    
==>v[1]
gremlin> v3 = g.addVertex([count:2])                                                           
==>v[2]
gremlin> v4 = g.addVertex([count:3])                                                           
==>v[3]
gremlin> v1.addEdge('child',v2)                                                                
==>e[4][0-child->1]
gremlin> v1.addEdge('child',v3)                                                                
==>e[5][0-child->2]
gremli                                                                                         
gremlin> v2.addEdge('child',v4)
==>e[6][1-child->3]
```

And then here's the calculation over each subtree within the full tree:

```
gremlin> g.V().filter{it.outE().hasNext()}.sideEffect{                                           
gremlin>   c=0;                                                                                  
gremlin>   it.as('a').out().sideEffect{leaf -> c+=(leaf.getProperty('count')?:0)}.loop('a'){true}.iterate()
gremlin>   it.setProperty('total',c)                                                                       
gremlin> }                                                                                                 
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
gremlin> g.v(0).total
==>5
gremlin> g.v(1).total                                                                                      
==>3
```

That query breaks down like this.  First, this piece:

```
g.V().filter{it.outE().hasNext()}
```

gets any portion of the tree that is not a leaf node (i.e. should have at least one outgoing edge to not be a leaf).  Second, we use `sideEffect` to process each root of a subtree:

```
it.as('a').out().sideEffect{leaf -> c+=(leaf.getProperty('count')?:0)}.loop('a'){true}.iterate()
```

storing the sum of the "count" property for each subtree in a variable called `c`.  There's a bit of groovy goodness there with the elvis operator (`?:`) to check for vertices without a "count" property and return a zero in those cases.  After you traverse the tree to calculate `c` you can just store the value of `c` in your root node of the subtree via:

```
it.setProperty('total',c)
```

Comment: >>you can just store the value of c in your root node of the subtree<< How?

Comment: `v1.setProperty('total',c)` - do you need something more?

Comment: Yes: calculate and cache those values for _each_ sub-tree, not for the whole tree.

Comment: I need to modify the query: property 'count' belongs to vertices that leaf vertices 'knows':v1 = g.addVertex()
v2 = g.addVertex()
v3 = g.addVertex()
v4 = g.addVertex() 
v5 = g.addVertex([count:3]) 
v6 = g.addVertex([count:2]) 
v1.addEdge('child',v2)  
v1.addEdge('child',v3)   
v2.addEdge('child',v4)
v3.addEdge('knows',v5)
v4.addEdge('knows',v6)

Comment: Adding edge labels doesn't really change the outcome of the query I provided.  It works independently of the edge labels as it is and I don't see a reason to constrain it to labels. Are you thinking that something no longer works as a result of the addition of the edge labels?

Comment: The original model was oversimplified. The real model has two trees connected to each other with specific relationships. The query has to reference specific label of edges like "knows". Example: v1 = g.addVertex()
v2 = g.addVertex()
v3 = g.addVertex()
v4 = g.addVertex() 
v5 = g.addVertex([count:3]) 
v6 = g.addVertex([count:2]) 
v1.addEdge('child',v2)  
v1.addEdge('child',v3)   
v2.addEdge('child',v4)
v5.addEdge('knows',v3)
v6.addEdge('knows',v4) Here v5 and v6 are part of another tree, not shown here.

Comment: Just filter on the edge labels then: `it.as('a').out('child','knows').sideEffect{leaf -> c+=(leaf.getProperty('count')?:0)}.loop('a'){true}.iterate()`  This constrains your traversal to just those edge labels: "child' and 'knows'.

Comment: What if the edge is in another direction: leaf.in('knows').getProperty('count') ?

Comment: I guess this is a way you could do it: `it.as('a').out('child').loop('a'){true}{true}.in('knows').sideEffect{leaf -> c+=leaf.getProperty('count')}.iterate()`

Comment: Is it possible to visit each subtree only once?

Comment: i suppose it's possible - but i think the traversal would have to be re-worked considerably and wouldn't be as easy to follow as the approach i provided. I think you probably need to spend more time playing around with Gremlin to start seeing how you would approach it that way.